# What is the best way to edit your own composer dependencies in a project?

Tags: php, git, symfony, composer-php

I have a symfony project with a few dependencies created by myself, i use these dependencies as VNC in a lot of projects.

The dependencies are symfony bundles and not able to use as standalone.

What's the best way to edit these dependencies? Since i have to see the changes and test if it works well.

At the moment i browse to the vendor directory to the target dependency, edit some stuff, see if its right in my development version and commit this change from the vendor directory.

I feel there is a better way! My zend studio doesnt like this way. It keeps building and building.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I sometimes clone a dependency bundle and then adjust app/autoload.php to point to it instead of the vendor directory.

Comment: I use composer to manage my own gihub dependencies. They are cloned into the vendors directory as usual. I then create a symlink in the src directory. Just be sure all changes are pushed before running composer update.

Answer (score 0):

Editing from vendor dir is OK in my opinion. It's a valid way but maybe not always the most ideal.

An alternative is to use the Composer PathRepository to load a local clone of your dependency into your project. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path for details on how to use that.

And BTW if the path repo is your thing, Studio is a tool that can help you work with them in a more systematic manner, see https://github.com/franzliedke/studio